# How to Upload PBIX file stored in Azure storage container to Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-runbook, azure-storage-files

My requirement is to upload the PBIX file stored in Azure storage container to Power BI Service without downloading it to local drive as I have to use the PowerShell script in Runbook Automation

Normally we can upload the PBIX file by giving local path like below

**$pbixFilePath = "C:\PBIXFileLocation\Test.pbix"**
$import = New-PowerBIReport -Path $pbixFilePath -Workspace $workspace -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
$import | Select-Object *

But now which path I have to use if the PBIX file is stored in Azure storage container and how the PowerShell script can be created? Is it possible?

Tried to list the blobs in the container with the Get-AzStorageBlob cmdlet and passed it as a path in above script and ended up with this error:
[image]

If possible please help me with a sample PowerShell script to achieve the above requirement

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be resolved by following my similar post in Azure platform

AnuragSingh-MSFT is a gem explained me clearly and resolved the issue

A basic understanding of Azure Automation runbook execution should help clarify this doubt. When runbooks are designed to authenticate and run against resources in Azure, they run in an Azure sandbox. Azure Automation assigns a worker to run each job during runbook execution in the sandbox. Please see this link for more details - Runbook execution environment These sandboxes are isolated environment with access to only some of the location/path/directories.

The following section should help answer the question - ... which path I have to use if the PBIX file is stored in Azure storage container and how the PowerShell script can be created?

The script snippet provided by Manu above would download the blob content in the same directory inside sandbox from where script is running. You can access this path inside the script using "." --> for example, if the blob that you are downloading is named testBlob, it will be available in location .\testBlob. ("." stands for current directory).

Therefore, the pbixFilePath can be initialized as $pbixFilePath = ".\Test.pbix"

Another option is to use $env:temp as mentioned in the question. It is one of the environments variable available on local machine (on your workstation) which generally resolves to C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp

In Azure Automation sandbox environment, this variable resolves to C:\Users\Client\Temp

Therefore, you could download the blob content using the following line:

Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Ctx -Destination $env:temp  #Destination parameter sets the target folder. By default it is local directory (.)

In this case, you would initialize pbixFilePath as $pbixFilePath = $env:temp+"\Test.pbix"

Either case is fine as long as the Automation limits are not exceeded.